# Gridview for angular 4 using ng-container and bootstrap is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, gridview

I have the following component template, which I am using to create a  grid view.

My template class

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="gridTemplate; context: {$implicit: item}">
      </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

My Component class

```
export class Grid implements OnInit  {
    @HostBinding('class') classes = 'row';
    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("component initialised");
    }
}
```

This is rendering the following HTML

```
<grid class="row">
    <!--bindings={
     "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]",
     "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
     }-->
     <div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                ....
            </div>
    </div>
</grid>
```

Since `.col-*` are not immediate children of `.row` the columns are not rendering properly and I get  [image: Colum renderin screwed]

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: remove the `div` which wraps the `col-sm-6` class.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov it's created by ng-container in angular when rendering the component template I think. I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Add a `ngIf` statement to equals `true` on cols container and it will work. More information: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives